# What can I remove to make an empty fragment look "cleaner"

Tags: android

When I create an empty fragment on Android Studio it generates the following code:

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link TestFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link TestFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public TestFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment TestFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static TestFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

It's quite complicated for an empty fragment. What is the purpose of each part that's created, and can I remove some of the code to make it "simpler"?
What's not necessary? Because when I create an empty activity it's much more "clean"

Comment: it's like buying a car, you may never use the boot but it's still there. I am not sure if it makes the car more complicated for the user? or would it be cleaner looking without it? Auto-generated classes tend to have minimum code necessary but surely you can get rid of  the parts you don't need if it is still not simple enough for you

Comment: You don't need to use auto-generated fragments - you can just create a new class, have it extend `Fragment` and you're done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> can I remove some of the code to make it "simpler"? What's not necessary?

You can actually remove all of the code. The only truly necessary part is the class definition itself:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

}
```

You don't even need the "required empty public constructor", because the compiler will add that for you. You should just never specify a constructor manually (except in very narrow cases that are outside the scope of this question).

---

Of course, **most** of the time you use fragments, you're going to use them to display information to the user, in which case you need to include the `onCreateView()` method:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    }
}
```

This method is responsible for creating the fragment's view. You aren't required to inflate a view (you can make one by hand and return that instead), but you *do* have to return some non-null view if you want the user to see anything. Whatever you return from this method can be retrieved later by calling `getView()`.

Note that it's perfectly valid to use a fragment with no view (e.g. a [retained fragment used only as a container for long-running tasks](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html)).

---

Another common thing to do with fragments is use `onAttach()` and `onDetach()` to cast the activity hosting the fragment to some `interface`. This lets the fragment class be used with multiple host activities, as long as each activity implements the interface.

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    private MyListenerInterface mListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.mListener = (MyListenerInterface) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        this.mListener = null;
    }

    public interface MyListenerInterface {
        void someMethod();
    }
}
```

You can just cast the context directly, without the `if` statement included in the generated code, because either way you're going to get a runtime exception thrown (you'll just get a `ClassCastException` instead).

You can define whatever methods you need in this interface.

---

Finally, the generated fragment is demonstrating the `newInstance()` pattern to use for "passing arguments" to the fragment. As mentioned before, you should never use a constructor with fragments, so how can you pass data to them? You can use the "arguments" `Bundle`, set that to the fragment, and then later retrieve the data using `getArguments()`.

Doing that all manually every time would be annoying, so you can wrap it all in a `newInstance()` static factory method to make things easier:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public static TestFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);

        TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        this.mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}
```

With this in place, anyone who needs to create an instance of this fragment can just call

```
TestFragment f = TestFragment.newInstance("Hello", "world");
```

Instead of having to write:

```
TestFragment f = new TestFragment();

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("param1", "Hello");
args.putString("param2", "world");

f.setArguments(args);
```

The `Bundle` class can handle many different types of data; this example is using Strings but you can use ints or Lists, etc. I've removed the `if` check from `onCreate()` because we *know* that the arguments bundle will always be non-null, so the check is useless. The only way for it to *not* be non-null is if someone doesn't call `newInstance()`, and we're much better off crashing and fixing that problem than trying to soldier on without the data we need.

You can call `getArguments()` from any method, not just `onCreate()`.

Comment: Very in depth answer, thank you. Must admit I did not understand all myself, I'm a real novice with Android.

Answer (score 0):

If your fragment is so simple you can use this instead

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    }

    //ADD THIS
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //YOUR LOGIC
    }
}
```

Other functions use for callbacks and share variable between fragments

This two is important

**onCreateView** : for inflate layout

**onActivityCreated** : for write logic codes